# Bytes of a string in Java

Tags: java, string

In Java, if I have a String `x`, how can I calculate the number of bytes in that string?

Comment: One might want to use a String to represent the body of an HTTP response and use the size to set the "Content-Length" header, which is specified in octets/bytes not characters. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13

Comment: A database column may have length restriction in bytes, e.g. VARCHAR2 (4000 BYTE) in Oracle. One might want to know the byte count of a String in desired encoding to know if the String would fit.

Comment: @iX3 Exactly the same as I was trying to do.

Comment: I believe there are two possible interpretations of this question, depending on the intent: One is "how much memory does my String use?". The answer to that is provided by @roozbeh below (maybe modulo VM subtleties like compressed OOPS). The other is, "if I convert the string to a byte[] how much memory would that byte array use?". This is the question that is answered by Andrzej Doyle. The difference can be large: "Hello World" in UTF8 is 11 bytes, but the String (per @roozbeh) is 50 bytes (if my math is right).

Comment: I should have added that the 11 bytes doesn't include the overhead of the byte[] object that holds them, so the comparison is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 343):

A string is a list of *characters* (i.e. code points).  The number of bytes taken to represent the string **depends entirely on which encoding you use to turn it into bytes**.

That said, you can turn the string into a byte array and then look at its size as follows:

```
// The input string for this test
final String string = "Hello World";

// Check length, in characters
System.out.println(string.length()); // prints "11"

// Check encoded sizes
final byte[] utf8Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(utf8Bytes.length); // prints "11"

final byte[] utf16Bytes= string.getBytes("UTF-16");
System.out.println(utf16Bytes.length); // prints "24"

final byte[] utf32Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-32");
System.out.println(utf32Bytes.length); // prints "44"

final byte[] isoBytes = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(isoBytes.length); // prints "11"

final byte[] winBytes = string.getBytes("CP1252");
System.out.println(winBytes.length); // prints "11"
```

So you see, even a simple "ASCII" string can have different number of bytes in its representation, depending which encoding is used.  Use whichever character set you're interested in for your case, as the argument to `getBytes()`.  And don't fall into the trap of assuming that UTF-8 represents *every* character as a single byte, as that's not true either:

```
final String interesting = "\uF93D\uF936\uF949\uF942"; // Chinese ideograms

// Check length, in characters
System.out.println(interesting.length()); // prints "4"

// Check encoded sizes
final byte[] utf8Bytes = interesting.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(utf8Bytes.length); // prints "12"

final byte[] utf16Bytes= interesting.getBytes("UTF-16");
System.out.println(utf16Bytes.length); // prints "10"

final byte[] utf32Bytes = interesting.getBytes("UTF-32");
System.out.println(utf32Bytes.length); // prints "16"

final byte[] isoBytes = interesting.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(isoBytes.length); // prints "4" (probably encoded "????")

final byte[] winBytes = interesting.getBytes("CP1252");
System.out.println(winBytes.length); // prints "4" (probably encoded "????")
```

(Note that if you don't provide a character set argument, the platform's *default character set* is used.  This might be useful in some contexts, but in general you should avoid depending on defaults, and always use an explicit character set when encoding/decoding is required.)

Comment: so again if i use getBytes().it will give me the length same as x.length am i wrong because i am not sure

Comment: @Green Ash The length of the byte array -- getBytes() -- and x.length MAY be equal but is not guaranteed to be so. It will be equal if all the characters are represented by a single byte each. This will always hold true for character encodings that use a single byte per character (or less), such as ISO-8859-1. UTF-8 uses either 1 or 2 bytes, so it depends on the exact characters in the string. Then there are character encodings that always use two bytes per character.

Comment: i like your answer :) , so they might in somehow be the same but not always am i right?                                               o.k. then is it ok to use the method without the parameter because it causing to me an error!!

Comment: @Green the point is that number of **bytes** is not always the same as the number of **characters**. The number of **bytes** depends on the character encoding that's used. You'll have to know which character encoding you're going to use and take that into account. What error are you getting? If you just use `getBytes()` it will use the default character encoding of your system.

Comment: @Kris - actually, UTF-8 uses 1, 2 **or 3** bytes per code point.

Comment: I've updated this answer to show some specific encoded sizes of both "ASCII" characters, and higher-plane characters.  And note that in the latter example, UTF-8 does indeed use 3 bytes per character.  @Green, as I noted at the end you should rarely (if ever) omit the character set, because then your answer isn't that useful - you don't know which character set you have the size in.

Comment: Can we say that a String char always take 4 bytes in memory for Java, since a String char is a code point?

Comment: @KorayTugay A `char` is **not** a code point.  [A `char` is 16 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (it's basically an unsigned `short`), so it always takes 2 bytes in memory.  An `int` is needed to represent a 4-byte code point, which is why methods like [String.codePointAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt-int-) return `int` and not `char`.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I see. I guess we can say: "A String char is always 2 bytes because Java uses UTF-16 for representing characters in memory." Correct?

Comment: @KorayTugay Yes, more or less.  You could argue about the order of cause and effect, though.  I'd be more inclined to state that a char is always 2 bytes because it is a primitive data type **defined** to be 2 bytes wide.  (And that the UTF-16 representation was mainly a consequence of this, rather than the other way round.)

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: Why is `"Hello World".getBytes("UTF-16").length` 24? I was expecting 22 = 2 bytes per character * 11 characters.

Comment: Nevermind. @finnw's answer below explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387559/1810962 .

Answer (score 70):

If you're running with 64-bit references:

```
sizeof(string) = 
8 + // object header used by the VM
8 + // 64-bit reference to char array (value)
8 + string.length() * 2 + // character array itself (object header + 16-bit chars)
4 + // offset integer
4 + // count integer
4 + // cached hash code
```

In other words:

```
sizeof(string) = 36 + string.length() * 2
```

On a 32-bit VM or a 64-bit VM with compressed OOPs (-XX:+UseCompressedOops), the references are 4 bytes. So the total would be:

```
sizeof(string) = 32 + string.length() * 2
```

This does not take into account the references to the string object.

Comment: I was assuming the question was about the number of bytes allocated in memory for a String object. If the question is about the number of bytes required to serialize the String, as others have pointed out, it depends on the encoding used.

Comment: Source for ur answer ? Thanks

Comment: Note: `sizeof` should be multiple of 8.

Answer (score 26):

The pedantic answer (though not necessarily the most useful one, depending on what you want to do with the result) is:

```
string.length() * 2
```

Java strings are physically stored in `UTF-16BE` encoding, which uses 2 bytes per code unit, and `String.length()` measures the length in UTF-16 code units, so this is equivalent to:

```
final byte[] utf16Bytes= string.getBytes("UTF-16BE");
System.out.println(utf16Bytes.length);
```

And this will tell you the size of the internal `char` array, in *bytes*.

Note: `"UTF-16"` will give a different result from `"UTF-16BE"` as the former encoding will insert a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), adding 2 bytes to the length of the array.

Comment: Roozbeh's answer is better, because it takes the other bytes into account as well.

Comment: @finnw Are you sure that the encoding is UTF-16BE and not UTF-16? According to the String class Javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), "A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format...".

Answer (score 19):

According to [How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java/88863#88863):

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
System.out.println(b.length);
```

Comment: but excuse me when i compile your code it gives me an error ; because of the parameter "UTF-8".where when i pass an empty parameter it gives me the length same as x.length . i misunderstand the concept. help please

Comment: @Green Ash, what version of Java do you have?

Comment: @Green Ash, what exception are you getting?

Comment: to be clear this is the output: test.java:11: unreported exception java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
        byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8"); 
                                     ^
1 error

Process completed.

Comment: @Green, try: `s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))`.

Answer (score 10):

A `String` instance allocates a certain amount of bytes in memory. Maybe you're looking at something like `sizeof("Hello World")` which would return the number of bytes allocated by the datastructure itself?

In Java, there's usually no need for a `sizeof` function, because we never allocate memory to store a data structure. We can have a look at the `String.java` file for a rough estimation, and we see some 'int', some references and a `char[]`. The [Java language specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1) defines, that a `char` ranges from 0 to 65535, so two bytes are sufficient to keep a single char in memory. But a JVM does not have to store one char in 2 bytes, it only has to guarantee, that the implementation of `char` can hold values of the defines range.

So `sizeof` really does not make any sense in Java. But, assuming that we have a large String and one `char` allocates two bytes, then the memory footprint of a `String` object is at least `2 * str.length()` in bytes.

Answer (score 8):

There's a method called [getBytes()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29). Use it wisely .

Comment: Wisely = don't use the one without a character set parameter.

Comment: Why? Is this an issue if i configure my environment to run with UTF8 encoding?

Comment: getBytes will also create and copy the array of bytes, so if you're talking long strings, this operation could get pricey.

Comment: @ticktock, if you're still around, yes but what is the alternative?  I got here hoping for a library function to return the storage needed so I can combine it into a larger allocation.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
Bytes.toBytes(x).length
```

Assuming you declared and initialized x before

Comment: Is this part of the standard Java library? I can't find the `Bytes` class.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid try catch, use:

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(b.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this using [apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html):

```
String src = "Hello"; //This will work with any serialisable object
System.out.println(
            "Object Size:" + SerializationUtils.serialize((Serializable) src).length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference `Charset` from some standard package instead of using String literal `"UTF-8"` then you can use `java.nio`

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
..
int numBytes = myString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8).length;
```