# How do i know if my GCM Message is small enough (< 4kb) to send? (How to get size of String?)

Tags: java, android, string, google-cloud-messaging

I want to embed data directly inside of a GCM (Google Cloud Message) in order to help my application skip a round trip to my server.

Google says the total data payload needs to fit inside 4kb. Data is sent using [key,value] pairs. Assuming I did something like this:

```
 String key = "key";
 String data = "data";
 Message message = new Message.Builder().addData(key, data).build();
 sender.send(message, regId, 5);
```

How can I know if the `String data` is less than 4kb? To my knowledge there's no way to really do a `String.getSize()` or similar.

Link to the documentation if curious:
http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#embed

Comment: Sorry, I meant the documentation of Google explaining embedding data directly into a GCM.

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/server-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/server/Message.html). Note you have to look at the static class [Message.Builder](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/server-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/server/Message.Builder.html) for the addData() method.

Comment: E.G. If using [Sender.post(..)](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/server-javadoc/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.html#post%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to send the message, note it throws an `IOException`.  If it throws an `IOException` in the event of a too large message, the answer to the question might boil down to `try` it.

Comment: I'm using `sender.send(...)`, not `sender.post(...)`. You are correct that I can try it. I was hoping to get a little more guidance on officially "how I know" so that in the event that it is too large, I gracefully handle it.

Comment: I did not understand the 2nd sentence.  It had short parts that made a kind of sense, but not when strung together.

Comment: I was just saying you're correct I can "just try it" but I was wondering how I can programatically and officially know when I have exceeded that size so that I can gracefully handle the error, if it happens, in my application.

Comment: *"I can gracefully handle the error, if it happens, in my application."*  That is what `catch` is for!

Comment: I realized just now that you meant `try` it and not "just try it" as in see if it works, lol. That's why our exchange made no sense.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following to get the bytes of a String:

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
int bytes = b.length;
```

Make sure that you specify the encoding of the `String`, as different encodings may take up a different number of bytes for the same String. In the above example, `UTF-8` is used as the encoding.

To convert the bytes into kB, just divide by `1024`.

EDIT: [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385653/1069068) a nice and detailed answer on the byte space of different encodings in Java from Geobits' comment.

Comment: Accepted answer because of the link to byte space of different encodings.

Answer (score 3):

```
int byteSize = data.length() * 2  // each char is 2 byte
```

**Updated**

```
int byteSize = data.getBytes("UTF-8").length // if you want to know the size in your desired encoding
```

Comment: This isn't true for all encodings.

Comment: I did read that a char was 2 bytes in Java, but as Raghav said that didn't seem to be 100% true. I think this answer might give me an estimate, but to be 100% I'd have to find out the type of encoding, correct?

Comment: You can set the type of encoding you want to use. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I run a couple of tests locally, seems like on the application side you can send a bundle that contains a key + value pair of about 4020 bytes before you start getting an error from gcm, while on the server side it's a bit more, about 4100 bytes.
Given this, to play safe we have decided to go with 4,000 bytes on either side.

Comment: so here sakis does it consider the key registration_ids also