# Spark Tuple get details/rdd per key

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark

I have these Rows:

```
(key1,Illinois|111|67342|...)
(key1,Illinois|121|67142|...)
(key2,Hawaii|113|67343|...)
(key1,Illinois|211|67442|...)
(key3,Hawaii|153|66343|...)
(key3,Ohio|193|68343|...)
```

(1) How do I get the unique keys?

(2) How do I get the number of rows PER key (key1 - 3 rows, key2 - 1 row, key 3 - 2 rows... so the output would be: 3,1,2)

(3) How do I get the byte size of rows PER key (5MB,2MB,3MB)

---

EDIT 1. this is my new code:

```
val rdd : RDD[(String, Array[String])] = ...
val rdd_res = rdd.groupByKey().map(row => (row._1, row._2.size, byteSize(row._2)))

val rddKeys = rdd_res.map(row => row._1)
val rddCount = rdd_res.map(row => row._2)     
val rddByteSize = rdd_res.map(row => row._3)
```

How do I implement the byteSize? I want to get the size that will be saved to disk.

---

EDIT 2.

```
  val rdd_res : RDD[(String, (Int, Int))] = rdd.aggregateByKey((0,0))((accum, value) => (accum._1 + 1, accum._2 + size(value)), (first, second) => (first._1 + second._1, first._2 + second._2))

  val rdd_res_keys = rdd_res.map(row=>row._1).collect().mkString(",")
  val rdd_res_count = rdd_res.map(row=>row._2).collect().map(_._1).mkString(",")
  val rdd_res_bytes = rdd_res.map(row=>row._2).collect().map(_._2).mkString(",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For distinct keys, you should switch the order:

```
rdd.keys.distinct.collect
```

But you technically get this from counting the keys into a map...via `countByKey` which returns a map of `key->count`

```
rdd.countByKey
```

And, to get the byte size, then you should review [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385623/bytes-of-a-string-in-java), as it is going to be dependent on decoding. But, once you've decided on a size method, then you can get it via:

```
rdd.aggregateByKey(0)((accum, value) => accum + size(value), _ + _)
```

Or, you can do it all in one:

```
rdd.aggregateByKey((0,0))((accum, value) => (accum._1 + 1, accum._2 + size(value), (first, second) => (first._1 + second._1, first._2 + second._2))
```

Which should yield an `RDD[(String, (Int, Int))]` where the first item in the tuple is the key count, and the second is the key size

Comment: @sophie Kiiiind of...You should only collect once and use that data. The data may sit on the hot path, but you are still running the same DAG 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have a pair RDD of (key, value).

You can get key and count using below

```
rdd_res = rdd_inp.countByKey
```

You can list of size for a key using below

```
rdd_size_res = rdd_inp.groupByKey().map((a,b)=>(a,size(b)))

def size(src: List[String]):List[String] = {

    src.map(a =>  (32 + a.length() * 2).toString())


  }
```

Please check if the above works for your scenario.

Comment: Edited my post to show the new code, I used map instead of foreach since the latter returns a Unit. For the implementation of byteSize, I can't make yours work. I tried row._2.mkString(",").length * 2 + 32) but it doesn't match the disk size. (577432 bytes vs 6.7MB)

Comment: I don't know how big the data set might be but reduceByKey would be a faster option for the count.

Comment: the rdd could contain 1 million rows. the distinct key would be around 100. im not sure how to do this by reduceByKey since I need the distinct key and 2 aggregates.

Comment: Sophie, the above mentioned size method will take input as list of strings for a particular key and return back a list. The formula 32+a.lenght()*2 is normally used to get size of a string that in occupies in JVM.

Comment: groupByKey followed by a map is inefficient... as the group shuffles everything all-all before the map, which then promptly loses it via map

Comment: Yes i agree ... agreegateByKey will be more efficient .. thanks for advice :)