# How can I use Android BLE app to write 20 bytes to CC2540?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am confused with how can I use Android app to write 20 bytes to CC2540.

I can write one byte(to one byte characteristic of 2540)easily by using the codes as bellow:

```
if ((charaProp | BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE) > 0) {
// If there is an active notification on a characteristic, clear
// it first so it doesn't update the data field on the user interface.
    if (mNotifyCharacteristic != null) {
         mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(mNotifyCharacteristic, false);
         mNotifyCharacteristic = null;
    }
    byte[] writev = {0x0c};
    characteristic.setValue(writev);
    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);

}
```

But if I want to write 20 bytes to a 20-bytes characteristic of 2540 , It seems wrong by changing the codes as follows:

```
String Mysend = "11111111111111111111";//20bytes
byte[] writev = Mysend.getBytes();
characteristic.setValue(writev);
mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

So, how can I use Android BLE app to write 20 bytes to CC2540?

Thanks! 
Callon

Comment: Confirm which character set your String is in. If its UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1. Else there may be more bytes than you expect. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4385653/295004 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/18571348/295004

Comment: Thank you for your advice.But if I just modify it by the codes as byte[] writev = {0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,};   it seems wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's going wrong, but some things to try:

- Check the return values of those two calls, because they can return false.
- Don't do more than 1 write in a row.
- Check the gattStatus provided to `BluetoothGattCallback.onCharacteristicWrite()` because it may give you a clue why it's failing.
- Try with 19 bytes, 18 bytes, etc. See what the failure threshold is. It may be that an MTU lower than 20 bytes was negotiated but I don't think that's possible. Try [BluetoothGatt.requestMtu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#requestMtu(int)) as well.
- Maybe the application logic on your peripheral (vs. the transport logic) is rejecting the write.
- As quick a sanity check that your code is correct, you can try [SweetBlue](https://github.com/iDevicesInc/SweetBlue), which does lots of error detection/correction.