# xquery function in OSB

Tags: xquery, osb

I am trying to calculate the size of the attachment in one of the service, i used below function "{fn:string-length($attachments)}" it will return the number of character, can any one tell how to calculate the size of the attachment in proxy service in oSb

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is possible with xquery or not.Another option is to use java callout activity in your proxy . Please refer this link to understand how to do it in java - [bytes of a string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385623/bytes-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Habin, actually my requirement is to check for the $attachment size and check if $attachment is in Base64, if not then convert it. Well in proxy service when i traverse to the path $attachments/ctx:attachment/ctx:body/*  i am not getting anything. Can you help me out here