# Calculate Json Array Size In Kb or Mb in android?

Tags: android, json, parse-platform

I want to calculate json array Size in KB/Mb. I have a condition where I need to calculate json Array size before uploading. It should not be more than 128 KB.

Comment: is the json array type String? or gson's JsonArray? or is it JSONArray from org.json package? Maybe you can post the relevant code so that we can see for ourselves?

Comment: Yes its JSONArray,not gson.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your `jsonArray` to `String` and use `string.getBytes().length` . It will give number of bytes used by the string to store the value.

Using those bytes you can calculate the size in any unit.

> String.getBytes().length is the number of bytes needed to represent
>   your string in the platform's default encoding. For example, if the
>   default encoding was UTF-16 (rare), it would be exactly 2x the value
>   returned by String.length(). More commonly, your platform encoding
>   will be a multi-byte encoding like UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

JSON is basically an `String` and encodings determine how much memory is required to store a `String`. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385653/370073) first.

Now with that knowledge you can simply proceed as follow:

```
JSON.toString().getBytes(YOUR_PREFERRED_ENCODING).length;
```

Comment: OutOfMemory recipe

Answer (score 1):

```
you can use the File.length() method to get the file size in bytes.
```

Comment: This solution need to generate the file but this could be useful in case of error to send the Json later without keeping it in memory. You should edit your answer to improve this a bit ;)