# Calculate Json Object Size In Kb or Mb in Kotlin?

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

I want to calculate json object Size in KB/Mb.

there is a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970411/calculate-json-array-size-in-kb-or-mb-in-android) but it's in Java. Kotlin doesn't allow us to get bytes of a String.

how can I do it in Kotlin?

Answer (score 3):

Is `str.toByteArray().size` the thing you are looking for [1]?

By the way, the approach described in the linked post converts the object to string and then looks at the string size. Note that this is only an *approximation* to the actual object size in memory.

---

[1] https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-byte-array.html