# how to find size of objects/json in bytes in JSON

Tags: java, json

Suppose we have 10mb of data in a table, with select query I am storing all those data in resultset object. Now I have to iterate over the resultset and convert it to specific json format.

I have to store only 1mb of data in that json message so that i can publish 1mb json message into kafka topic.
SO how to check the size of json message in bytes?

jsonObject.toString().getBytes().length;
is this correct?

Comment: You can't really be sure from the Java side how much storage space a single character will take, because it's only determined on the storage side.

Comment: Similar topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970411/calculate-json-array-size-in-kb-or-mb-in-android

Comment: @MikeKim `getBytes` gets the data in a string in a particular encoding, so it is independent of how Java Strings represent characters

Comment: Removing Kafka tag since question is about  JVM internals. Removing library tags since they're not relevant for finding size of a String/byte array

Comment: If size is a truly a concern, use a binary format like Protobuf and enable Kafka message compression. Lastly, Kafka can easily support larger events, if configured