# Creating regular expression validation for naming objects

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I wanted to make a validator for amazon following these specification http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-keys.

And I created my pattern as:

```
private static Pattern objectKeyNamePtrn = Pattern.compile("^[a-z0-9_-!.*'()]{6,30}$");
```

But, I am getting error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>   Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character
>   range near index 11 ^[a-z0-9_-!.*'()]{6,30}$

I tried escaping with '\' but didn't work.

And also Amazon guys says, The name for a key is a sequence of Unicode characters whose UTF-8 encoding is at most 1024 bytes long.

How should I check that, using regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is here: "_-!". The compiler is trying to interpret that sequence as a range of characters instead of individual characters.

Try reordering them, or use an escape character like so: "_\-!".

Two backslashes are required to create the escape character in java.

Edit: to check if the string is less than 1024 bytes, see this question: [bytes of a string in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385623/bytes-of-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thats correct. I avoided that , but it should be "_\\-!" for Java. Thanks