# Storing numbers in Strings. Is it resources waste?

Tags: java, types

Say I have an ArrayList of type String that stores numbers only. Am I wasting my resources? Is String bigger than int or short? I can't find the size of a String anywhere and came up with this dumb question that intrigues me.

Is short the most efficient data type for storing 5 digit numbers?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385623/bytes-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: String uses as much memory as it takes to store each character. the more characters, the more memory it uses

Comment: A string is just an immutable `char[]`. A `char` is 16 bits, how many `char`s are used depends on the encoding, but for the max int value of 2147483647 you need 10 characters while this fits into one 32 bit int. More importantly, _why is this an issue_? This seems like code smell.

Comment: `short` is not at all the best type to store a 5 digit number. `Short.MAX_VALUE` (2^15-1) is 32767, which doesn't cover the full range of 0-99999.

Answer (score 3):

The size of a String object is very flexible. Each character in the String takes one or two bytes, so storing a 5 digit number is at least 5 bytes. Plus there is some overhead for the `String` object. On the other hand, an int is 32-bits which is only 4 bytes.

A more important issue is that it is difficult to perform arithmetic with numbers stored as strings. You will have to implement methods to add, subtract, multiply, and divide. With `int` you have built in operators.

Comment: and int stores up to the value of `2,147,483,647`

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8 a `String` is intern just a `char[]` which contains all characters that are used in the `String`. In this case, the `int` with 32 bits is bigger than 1 `char` with 16 bit.

In Java 9 there is a `byte[]` instead of a `char[]` for a `String`

Now it's on you to figure out which is the more efficient type for you to use.

Answer (score 2):

String and Integer are objects and int is primitive type. so Objects use alot more memory whereas primitive types don't.
for example if you have a primitive type as:

```
int i = 5;
```

for example in memory address 10 the value 5 will be saved and i knows address 10

but for objects as:

```
Integer i = new Integer(5):
```

the value of 5 will be saved in for example address 2 and address 10 (which is i variable) will reference to address 2 which takes more memory. When a new object is created, a composite memory block consisting of a series of consecutive blocks, one for each instance variable, is created which takes alot more memory.

String is an object, an special object but still an object . it's special because for example it doesn't need `new`