# java error converting to unicode

Tags: java, android, unicode

I am getting a java exception when I convert a string to unicode:

```
public static boolean sendOutgoingSms(String phoneNumber, String message,
            Context context) {
    try {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(), 0);
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        message = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(message).toString();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, pi, null);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Trace.e("Failed to send outgoing sms", ex);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Error:

```
"java.nio.ReadWriteHeapByteBuffer, status: capacity=8 position=0 limit=4"
```

Am I using the Charset,forName in a wrong way?

Comment: I don't get that error. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That doesn't look like an exception either...

Comment: What if you  made "hi" just "h" ?

Comment: did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8

Comment: I have added the entire method snippet. This is on android.

Comment: I am not familiar with Android dev, but from the API of SmsManager I don't see any reason you need to do such a strange String massaging. Simply pass the message directly to sendTextMessage should work (as it is what expected from SmsManager.sendTextMessage()) .  SmsManager should take care of the charset handling inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings internally are in Unicode. The only problem here, is that a java source file can be in several encodings, hence a string constant like `"hi"` could be encoded differently by the javac compiler.

Make sure that the *editor* and the *compiler* use the same encoding. Optimally UTF-8 for international projects. If you are using a build infrastructure like **maven** you can explicitly declare it there.

Then `String message = "eĥoŝanĝo ĉiuĵaŭde";` is fine.

You can use the java tool **native2ascii** to encode special chars, so the java source is pure ASCII,

Convert from Windows Latin-1 to `\uXXXX` u-encoding (ASCII remains).

```
native2ascii -encoding windows-1252 A.java temp.txt
```

Reverse encode the java to UTF-8:

```
native2ascii -reverse -encoding UTF-8 temp.txt A.java
```

---

After the addition to the question, I think the problem of special characters lies in the SMS part. The success strongly depends on provider and receiving phones. Best would be to go for an accepted transliteration for the concerned language: Cyrillic to Latin or so.

Comment: I changed the question section with the exact code. Error still seems to be happening

Comment: Charset usage is totally unneeded.