# How to safely encode Strings as bytes over sockets for chat app

Tags: java, swing, sockets, encoding, character-encoding

For a chat app in Java/Swing over Java sockets, is this enough to ensure text is encoded/displayed properly while avoiding platform-specific encoding? (the client may run on Windows, Linux, Mac)

```
//sending
bytes chatMsgAsBytes = textField.getText().getBytes("UTF-8");
socketOutputStream.write(chatMsgAsBytes);
```

.

```
//receiving
byte[] bytes = ...
socketInputStream.read(bytes);
textField.setText( new String(bytes,"UTF-8"));
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5729806/791406), but is there anything else major to consider to avoid issues with platform-specific encoding when sending bytes over the network?

Comment: This should work for any system, regardless of it's default encoding.

Comment: You could also use  [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)/[`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) which have encoding safe `String` interchange methods built in.

Answer (score 1):

I have used ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream to achive this.

Socket:

```
  Socket cliente = new Socket(host, port);
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
  ObjectInputStream ois= new ObjectInputStream(cliente.getInputStream());
```

To send:

```
  String message="Hi";
  oos.writeObject(m);
  oos.flush();
```

To receive:

```
 String msg = (String)ois.readObject();
```

Comment: Also an option since ObjectOutputStream uses modified UTF-8 internally.