# Charset trouble (ø as 00F8)

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am getting a string from our database (third party tool) - and I have a trouble with one 
name - sometimes it is right "Tarsøy", and all runs smoothly but sometimes it is "Tars00F8y".
And this ruins the process - I have tried to write some validator function via `URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8")` that gets a string and return validated one but not succeed.

this is how I get a sting from our base:

```
Database.WIKI.get(index); // the index is the ID of the string 
                            // this is no sql DB
```

now about "sometimes" - it means that this code just works different =) I think that is connected with inner DB exceptions or so. So I am trying to do something like `validate(Database.WIKI.get(index))`
May be I should try something like [Encode String to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: Can you show us how you read the `String` from the database and how you use it?

Comment: If it works sometimes it sounds like the problem is bad data in the database.

Comment: You should provide a better definition of “sometimes”. Btw., it’s not surprising that your attempt with `URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8")` failed. The string `"Tars00F8y"`is neither a URL nor UTF-8 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, JavaScript and (especially interesting) JSON there exists the notation `\u00F8` for `ø`. I think this was sent to the database, maybe from a specific browser on a specific computer locale. `\u` disappeared and voilà. Maybe it is still as invisible control character in the string. That would be nice for repairs.

My guess is JSON data; however normally JSON libraries should parse u-escaped characters. That is weird.

Check what happens when storing `"x\\u00FDx"`. Is the char length 6 or maybe 7 (lucky).

Some sanity checks: assuming you work in UTF-8, especially if the data arrive by HTML or JS:

- Content-Type header text/html; charset=UTF-8
- (Optional) meta tag with charset=UTF-8
- `<form action="..." accept-charset="UTF-8">`
- JSON: `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"`

Comment: @curiousity Did you find a repair/solution?

Comment: Yes, I have cleared the DB record from where was the data for JSON parsed and re-write it here as UTF-8 (via bites).