# Java - how to change byte[] or String encoding?

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding, byte

I have a plain Java `String` (ofc in `UTF-16` encoding). How can I convert this String into `Windows-1251` encoding and then get bytes of it, or convert `UTF-16` bytes to `Windows-1251` bytes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encode String to UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice it

Comment: Answer is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8
I userd `Charset.forName()`