# How do I change string encoding?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

I have a problem. I have a `String`

```
String str="Привет";
```

that I try to send to a server through a `POST` request. The website that receives this string has the `windows-1251` charset (on server all files, data, text etc have windows-1251).It shows all its data well, except from Russian symbols received from my Java app. I googled this problem an how can I change string encoding in my Java app but I still got no solution.

I tried to do this

```
String str=new String("Привет".getBytes("utf-8"),"cp1251");
```

but that didn't help.

So the question is: how do I convert Java `utf-8` string into `cp1251` so that the web server that accepts `cp1251` encoding shows all data received from me properly.

This is how I send request:

```
protected Map<String, String> getFromUrl(String url, boolean post, Map<String,String> postParams, Map<String,String> files, boolean options, String fbt, String asFile){
    dataStream=null;
    bodyStream=null;
    url=url.replaceAll("(?iu)^(http(s?)[://]*)+", "http$2://").replaceAll("(\\+|\\s+)", "%20");
    if(url.matches("(?iu)^https://.*$"))return getFromUrlSSL(url,post,postParams,files,options,fbt,asFile);
    else if(!url.matches("(?iu)^((http(s?))|ftp)://.*$"))url="http://"+url;
    if(url.length()>2048)url=url.substring(0,2048);
    System.out.println("/*Trying to connect to "+url+"*/");
    Map<String, String> mp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String host = this.getHostName(url), content = "", UA = this.getUA(), cookie = this.getCookie(host, UA), referer = "http://"+host+"/";
    try{
        mp.put("User-Agent",UA);
        mp.put("cookies",cookie);
        URL U = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)U.openConnection();
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", host);
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", UA);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "115");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        if(arp!=null)for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : arp.entrySet())conn.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
        if(referer != null&&(arp==null||!arp.containsKey("Referer")))conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", referer);
        if(cookie != null && !cookie.contentEquals(""))conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
        if(post&&(postParams!=null&&postParams.size()>0||files!=null&&files.size()>0)){
            if(!options)conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            else conn.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os;
            BufferedWriter writer;
            if(files!=null&&files.size()>0){
                String boundary = Long.toHexString(System.currentTimeMillis());
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);

                os=conn.getOutputStream();
                writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));;
                if(postParams!=null&&postParams.size()>0){
                    Iterator it=postParams.entrySet().iterator();
                    while(it.hasNext()){
                        Map.Entry<String,String> pair=(Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
                        writer.append("--" + boundary).append("\r\n");
                        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+pair.getKey()+"\"").append("\r\n");
                        writer.append("\r\n");
                        writer.append(pair.getValue()).append("\r\n");
                    }
                }

                Iterator fIt=files.entrySet().iterator();
                while(fIt.hasNext())try{
                    Map.Entry<String, String> fPair=(Map.Entry<String, String>)fIt.next();
                    String filename=fPair.getValue();
                    System.out.println("/*"+filename+"*/");
                    if(!filename.matches("(?iu)^[\\s\\S]*?Content-Disposition. form-data[\\s\\S]*$")){
                        File file=null;
                        System.out.println("/*"+filename+"*/");
                        String fe=filename.matches("(?iu)^.*?(\\.[a-z0-9]{1,5})$")?filename.replaceAll("(?iu)^.*?(\\.[a-z0-9]{1,5})$","$1"):".jpg";
                        if(filename.matches("(?iu)^(http|ftp).*$")){
                            getFileFromUrl(filename,System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\curFile"+fe);
                            file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\curFile"+fe);
                        }
                        else file = new File(filename);
                        try{
                            BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(file);
                            int width = bimg.getWidth();
                            int height = bimg.getHeight();
                            if(width<150||height<150)file=null;
                            else if(width/height>3||height/width>3)file=null;
                            else if(width>1024||height>1024){
                                float ii=width/height,w=ii>0?1024:height/width*1024,h=ii>0?width/height*1024:1024;
                                int type = bimg.getType() == 0? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : bimg.getType();
                                BufferedImage img = resizeImage(bimg,type,(int)w,(int)h);
                                ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
                                if(filename.matches("(?iu)^(http|ftp).*$"))file = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\curFile"+fe);
                                else new File(filename);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
                            Error.showError("Browser.getFromUrl() can't get data from url",e);
                            return new HashMap<String,String>(){{put("error","fileerror");}};
                        }
                        if(file!=null){
                            writer.append("--" + boundary).append("\r\n");
                            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+fPair.getKey()+"\"; filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"").append("\r\n");
                            writer.append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream").append("\r\n");
                            writer.append("\r\n").flush();
                            InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
                            //System.out.println(conn.getOutputStream());
                            try{
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                for(int length = 0;(length = input.read(buffer))>0;)os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                os.flush();
                            }
                            finally{try{input.close();}catch (IOException logOrIgnore){}}
                            writer.append("\r\n").flush();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Error.showError("Browser.getFromUrl() can't get data from url",e);
                    return new HashMap<String,String>(){{put("error","fileerror");}};
                }
                writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append("\r\n");
            }
            else{
                String params="";
                Iterator it=postParams.entrySet().iterator();
                while(it.hasNext()){
                    Map.Entry<String,String> pair=(Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
                    //System.out.println(pair.getKey()+"="+pair.getValue());
                    /*if(pair.getKey().trim().contentEquals("")&&arp.get("Content-Type")!=null&&arp.get("Content-Type").matches("(?iu)^[\\s\\S]*?application/json[\\s\\S]$"))params+=pair.getValue();
                    else */
                    params+=URLEncoder.encode(pair.getKey(),"UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(pair.getValue(),"UTF-8")+"&";
                }
                params=params.replaceAll("&+$","");
                if(fbt!=null)conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",fbt);
                os=conn.getOutputStream();
                writer=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                if(fbt!=null){
                    writer.append("Content-Type: "+fbt).append("\r\n");
                    writer.append("Content-Length: "+params.length()).append("\r\n").append("\r\n");
                    if(fbt.matches("(?iu)^.*boundary=.*$")){
                        String boundary=fbt.replaceAll("(?iu)^[\\s\\S]*?boundary=([^;]+)[\\s\\S]*$","$1");
                        writer.append(boundary).append("\r\n");
                        it=postParams.entrySet().iterator();
                        //System.out.println(boundary);System.exit(1);
                        while(it.hasNext()){
                            Map.Entry<String,String> pair=(Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
                            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+pair.getKey()+"\"").append("\r\n\r\n");
                            writer.append(pair.getValue()).append("\r\n");
                            writer.append(boundary).append("\r\n");
                        }
                    }
                    else writer.append(params.replaceAll("(^[=&\\s])|([\\s=&]$)",""));
                }
                else writer.write(params.replaceAll("(^[=&\\s])|([\\s=&]$)",""));
            }
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            //System.out.println(conn.getOutputStream());
            conn.setConnectTimeout(120000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(120000);
        }
        else{
            conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(7000);
        }
        conn.connect();
        //System.out.println(mp.get("cookies"));
        mp = processResponseHeaders(conn.getHeaderFields());
        //System.out.println(mp.get("cookies"));
        if(mp.get("cookies")!=null && !mp.get("cookies").trim().contentEquals("") && !mp.get("cookies").contentEquals(cookie))this.setCookie(host, UA, cookie+"; "+mp.get("cookies"));
        if((needRedirect!=null&&!needRedirect.contentEquals("")) && curRedirect<5){
            if(!needRedirect.matches("(?i)^(.{3,5}?://)[\\s\\S]*$"))needRedirect = needRedirect.replaceAll("^([^\\.]*?://)?[^/\\?\\=\\&]*([/\\?\\=\\&])", url.replaceAll("^((http[s]?|ftp)://([^/\\?\\=\\&]*))[\\s\\S]*$","$1")+"$2");
            return getFromUrl(needRedirect,false,null,null,false,null,asFile);
        }
        try{
            dataStream = conn.getErrorStream() != null ? conn.getErrorStream() : conn.getInputStream();
            bodyStream = mp.get("content-encoding")!=null && mp.get("content-encoding").equalsIgnoreCase("gzip") ? new BufferedInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(dataStream)) : new BufferedInputStream(dataStream);
            if(asFile!=null&&!asFile.trim().contentEquals(""))this.getFileFromUrlWIS(bodyStream,asFile);
            else content = parseByteData(readToByteBuffer(bodyStream, 1024 * 1024), getCharsetFromContentType(conn.getContentType()));
        }
        catch(Exception e){Error.showError("Browser.getFromUrl() can't get data from url",e);}
        finally{
            if(bodyStream != null)bodyStream.close();
            if(dataStream != null)dataStream.close();
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e){Error.showError("Browser.getFromUrl() can't get data from url",e);}
    mp.put("url", url);
    mp.put("content", content.replaceAll("&nbsp;", " ")/*.replaceAll("<!--[\\s\\S]*?-->", "")*/.replaceAll("[\r\n\t]","").replaceAll("\\s+", " "));
    curRedirect=0;
    return mp;
}
```

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8

Comment: from where are you hitting this post request a servlet , or a javascript/query  code.?

Answer (score 0):

Strings are in UTF-16 in Java. Bytes are in other encodings. Bytes are sent over the network. Strings are not. When you are sending bytes to the network, use a CharsetEncoder to obtain the bytes in the encoding you desire, and send those over the network. You haven't shown the code that actually sends data over the network, so it's not possible to be more precise.