# Is this the right way to change the charset of a String?

Tags: java, character-encoding

Is this the right way to change the charset of a String?

```
String str = "helloworld你好世界"
String str2 = new String(str.getBytes("GBK"), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(str2);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode String to UTF-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: Your question is unclear: a String doesn't have a charset...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the "charset" of a java.lang.String object. The "set of characters" that can be used as elements is defined by Unicode. The encoding is fixed as UTF-16.

If you want the sequence of bytes representing the UTF-8 encoding of a java.lang.String s, use

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes( "UTF-8" );
```

Most of the time, this conversion will be done during I/O, according to your system's default character set anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Charset is just a way to read a string, it's just define the way to convert between string and byte[].

Your code cannot change the charset of the string. Your code just defines a wrong way to read a string.