# How to convert String to utf-8 and still get results as String

Tags: java, utf-8

I'm trying to encode a string into utf-8 and I want the result as a String, is there a way to easily get it?

Comment: I would suggest the second solution provided in (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that has an encoding is a Byte array PLUS encoding. So if you need UTF-8 data, then you need a byte[] PLUS encoding.

See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Or just do:

```
Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode(myString)
```

Or

```
byte[] ptext = String.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

All in same question