# Can't convert UTF-8 from Scanner to Console(System.out) with original result in Java

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I know that java 8 uses UTF-8 as standard encoding. When i read string from standard-input(System.in) with Scanner using "UTF-8" then try to print it to console and the string is not in right origin as I show beneath ,but with the initialized string the console show right original string without unexpected result.How can i fix this?Please help me!
I use Scanner not String constructor to encode input.I know how to convert input to UTF-8 but something wrong happened to my result and asked for the reason and solution to solve that problem ,not asking for the way to encode string with UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class charset {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
        Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");
        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        System.out.println("á ă ấ");
    }
}
```

-Here is my output:

```
run:

UTF-8

á ă ấ

� ? ?

á ă ấ

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode String to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: I use Scanner not String constructor to encode input.I know how to convert input to UTF-8 but something wrong happened to my result and asked for the reason and solution to solve that problem ,not asking for the way to encode string with UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

try this one
[set utf8 eclipse](https://www.google.co.il/amp/s/decoding.wordpress.com/2010/03/18/eclipse-how-to-change-the-console-output-encoding/amp/)
If its not helping try to read from file instead of console to see what happens.

Comment: i use netbeans and i have tried to read from file instead console(Scanner(System.in)) as you said but nothing changes

Comment: Did you try to write into file as well?

Comment: yeap i 've just done it and the result still wrong@@~the characters not in origin