# how to remove special characters from string

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I have a String called

```
String s = "ConstituciÃ³n GarantÃ­a";
```

I want to convert it to `Constitución garantía`.

This is a Spanish keyword. How can I convert it?

Comment: looks like you have encoding problems, solve that in stead of trying to change the string (and remember, if this comes from logging, the logging an also be the problem and not the code)

Comment: Your input ``String s`` is already broken.

Comment: Its an encoding issue, have a look at -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729806/encode-string-to-utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have described is an XY problem. It's the encoding issue and there might appear more of the characters that need to be replaced. Instead of replacing them one by one, you need to encode the whole String to `UTF-8`.

```
String s = "ConstituciÃ³n GarantÃ­a"; 
byte[] ptext = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1); 
String string = new String(ptext, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);      
System.out.println(string);                                 // Constitución Garantía
```

Consider fixing the encoding of a source where the string comes from before you actually start to work with it.