# JNDI does not decode BASE64 string properly when connecting to LDAP

Tags: java, ldap, base64, jndi, decode

I am using JNDI to connect to a LDAP server. A few attributes on the server are stored as BASE64 string.

However, when I query the server and get results back. These attributes are already decoded but not properly. For example, "abc-def@domain.com" may be decoded as "abcûdef@domain.com".

Any idea on how can I fix this?

Added:

The original BASE64 string is:

```
Q049XCtHcm91cCBBUFNHLU9uLWJvYXJkaW5n4oCTTllDLE9VPU5ZQyxPV
 20=
```

Comment: Can you provide the BASE64 strings in question?

Comment: So I get some unicode characters when I decode it.  Is that expected?  See: http://pastebin.com/xtAMf276

Comment: For the most part, the problem is the char between "on-boarding" and "NYC", it is supposed to be a dash.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be a problem between UTF16, which is Java's native character format, and UTF8.  The entity that is encoding the string must be UTF8.

To decode a string from UTF8 use:

```
// to decode a string
String decoded = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(encoded.getBytes()), "UTF8");
```

That gives me the right output.  If you need to convert a UTF8 string to be UTF16 you'd do:

```
new String(utf8String.getBytes(), "UTF8");
```

Comment: However, outlook can decode this properly. Also, if you use this link: http://coderstoolbox.net/string/, put in the string, and choose UTF-8, the dash can be decoded properly.

Comment: Java's default encoding is UTF-16 not UTF-8.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/643713/179850

Comment: Here's how to do the conversion from UTF8: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java

Comment: I've edited my answer with the solution if your input is UTF8

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am a newbie on this, another problem i have now is that from JNDI I get the string "CN=+Group APSG-On-boarding‚ÄìNYC,OU=NYC,O", rather than the original bytes.

Comment: To convert your string from UTF8 to UTF16 you do:  new String(jndiString.getBytes(), "UTF8");

Comment: I can't help you anymore, sorry.  It is definitely a charset issue.  Here are the Java supported character sets:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html