# decode JSON with cyrillic characters

Tags: java, json

I have this JSON string:

```
[{
    "dpeartment":"\u0418\u0437\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u043e\u0442\u0434\u0435\u043b",
    "position":"\u0418\u0437\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u0437\u0438\u0446\u0438\u044f"
 },{
    "dpeartment":"\u041c\u0422\u0426 \u0438 \u0441\u043a\u043b\u0430\u0434\u043e\u0432\u043e \u0441\u0442\u043e\u043f\u0430\u043d\u0441\u0442\u0432\u043e",
    "position":"\u0418\u0437\u0431\u0435\u0440\u0435\u0442\u0435 \u043f\u043e\u0437\u0438\u0446\u0438\u044f"
}]
```

It contains cyrillic characters that I want to convert to normal, readable UTF-8 encoded strings. How to decode the JSON and convert the cyrillic text to a readable UTF-8 string?
Does java have any built-in classes for this?

Comment: Why do you want a UTF-8 String?  Why does a regular UTF-16 `java.lang.String` not suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Towards the bottom of http://json.org/ is a list of Java libraries for parsing and formatting JSON.  [`org.json`](http://www.json.org/java/index.html) or [json-simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples) for example.

> How to decode the JSON and convert the cyrillic text to a readable UTF-8 string?

Any of them should expose the quoted strings in your JSON data bundle as `java.lang.String`s which expose the strings content as a series of UTF-16 code-units.  If you then want a `byte[]` with UTF-8 octets, see [How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java) .