# Encoding JSON to support UTF-8 characters in an android app

Tags: android, json, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to display `utf-8` character in a `ListView` in my android app, but what appears is series of question mark?????  This is what the output looks like:

```
[{"ImageID":"1","ItemID":"Item1","ItemID_AM":"????
???","ImagePath":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2\/android\/Pagination\/pics\/pic_a.png"},{"ImageID":"2","ItemID":"Item2","ItemID_AM":"????
????","ImagePath":"http:\/\/10.0.2.2\/android\/Pagination\/pics\/pic_b.png"},...
```

I already used: `header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');`
But nothing changed. Can someone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Does your list view really display JSON? Or is this the JSON input you are showing in your question? Please use fiddler or a similar tool to capture the transmitted JSON data and add it to your question. And please add the code for requesting the data and parsing the JSON as well.

Comment: Could you try to show the complete JSON in your textView, your JSON might not be correct 'utf-8' encoded. If your data comes from a db try this: mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbLink);

Comment: I've a database and I used php to convert the results into json format, and then I want it to be displayed in my android ListView.

Comment: So the checklist should look like this: 1.) Charset of your TEXT/VARCHAR = utf-8?  2. mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbLink); ?   3. php-code saved as utf8 charset

Comment: But in mysql database all the characters are displayed correctly, but when I browse it in json, well the question mark "????" appears. So the question mark also displayed in my android ListView, because that is what it gets from the json.

Comment: What happens when you load the JSON with a browser?

Comment: **Alastair McCormack** it displays series of question marks. As a result it, it also displays question mark in my android ListView.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362095/displaying-unicode-characters-in-json/19382335#19382335

Answer (score 1):

Java strings use Unicode and the JSON strings are UTF-8 encoded. Most likely, you must convert the UTF-8 JSON to Unicode.

Search: [java string utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+is%3Aq+string+utf8), for example [How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/88838/1741542)

The easiest way though, would be to let an appropriate JSON library do the decoding. Maybe [org.json - Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) or [How to parse JSON in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605913/1741542) is of help.

*Update:*

Maybe everything is fine and it is just the font not capable of displaying the needed characters. If this is the case, the solution to the problem would be to install an appropriate font.

Comment: Okay Olaf I'll check it out.

Comment: what is the encoding of Java strings ? Every unicode has to be encoded to be able to store on memory.

Comment: See [Oracle - Class String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) "A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format ...". There's also [Oracle - Unicode Character Representations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) "The char data type ... are based on the original Unicode specification, which defined characters as fixed-width 16-bit entities." Stackoverflow also has quite a few questions on the subject, http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+string+internal+representation