# Java Output UTF-8 to Real Characters?

Tags: java, utf-8

**In Java, how can I output UTF-8 to real string?**

```
     我们

     \u6211\u4eec

        String str = new String("\u6211\u4eec"); 
       System.out.println(str); // still ouput \u6211\u4eec, but I expect 我们 to be an output

-----
String tmp = request.getParameter("tag");
        System.out.println("request:"+tmp);
        System.out.println("character set :"+request.getCharacterEncoding());       
        String tmp1 = new String("\u6211\u4eec");       
        System.out.println("string equal:"+(tmp.equalsIgnoreCase(tmp1)));
        String tag = new String(tmp);       
        System.out.println(tag);

request:\u6211\u4eec
character set :UTF-8
string equal:false
\u6211\u4eec
```

From the output, the value from the request is the same as the string value of `tmp1`, but why does `equalsIgnoreCase` output `false`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Java String are encoded in UTF-16. I do not see any problem in your code, I would believe the problem comes from your console and it doesn't show correctly the content of the String.

If you are using eclipse, change your console encoding here to UTF-8

```
Eclipse > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text file encoding
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try to display just one of them? like

```
   String str = new String("\u6211"); 
   System.out.println(str);
```

I bet there is a problem in how you create that string.