# How to save image in database using sqlite database

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

**MAIN**

> please help me am try to store image as blob  in sqlite but i got like string format i don't know what i am doing wrong..

```
public byte[] photo=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button insert=(Button)findViewById(R.id.insert);

    final SQLiteDatabase db;
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("demo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists demo1(Dp BLOB );");
    insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            //ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bos);
            photo=bos.toByteArray();
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO demo1(Dp)VALUES('"+photo+"')");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: _Image saving in data base like Dp="[B@40d0c7e8"_

Comment: it is normal, consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536054/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-string-and-vice-versa) and also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java)

Comment: _so we can't save in normal database correct?_

Comment: yep, sqlite db does not support feature like save image as it is, only primitive types like string