# UTF-8 encoded string's byte count isn't as expected

Tags: java

I am not able to understand this: Why does the given code print out `12` and not `11` altough `hello world` has only 11 characters?

```
byte[] byteArray = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").array();
System.out.println(byteArray.length);
```

Comment: When you debug this, what bytes are in the array?  What characters in UTF-8 do they map to?

Comment: There is "End of String" special character after it. I guess.

Comment: Why do you expect it to be 11?

Answer (score 7):

The `array` method of `ByteBuffer` returns the array backing the buffer, but not all bytes are significant. Only the bytes up to `limit` are used. The following returns 11 as expected:

```
int limit = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").limit();
System.out.println(limit);
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy to see if you debug the array:

```
b=68, char=h
b=65, char=e
b=6C, char=l
b=6C, char=l
b=6F, char=o
b=20, char= 
b=77, char=w
b=6F, char=o
b=72, char=r
b=6C, char=l
b=64, char=d
b=0, char=
```

So last character is \u0000

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but to get the byte array of a string, why not just use:

```
String s = "hello world";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");

assertEquals(s.length(), b.length);
```

More information in this answer:

[How to convert Strings to and from UTF8 byte arrays in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java/88863#88863)

Answer (score 0):

Using this program, you can figure out what bytes the byte array contains:

```
byte[] byteArray = Charset.forName("UTF-8").encode("hello world").encoded.array();
for(int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(byteArray[i]+" - "+((char)byteArray[i]));
}
```

The bytes are (decimal):

```
104 101 108 108  111 32 119 111  114 108 100 0
```

The first 11 characters are the UTF-8 encoded string `hello world`, as expected. The last byte is the [Null character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character), which is used to represent nothing at all.

To deal with this, just use the `.limit()` method of `ByteBuffer` as mentioned above.