# How to write data to Google Cloud SQL in UTF-8

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I develop application with Google App Engine and Google Cloud SQL 
I am writing data in to Google Cloud SQL in Hebrew the data is written as "????"
how can I transform it to UTF-8
Thank you

example of entity

```
package com.darimpo.shared.entities;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import com.darimpo.shared.utilities.Utilities.Parameters;

@Entity
@Table(name = "AddressesTable")
public class Address extends Base {

private long buildingId;
private long floorId;
private long apartmentId;   
private long userId;

@Transient
private String floorName;
@Transient
private String apartmentName;

public Address() {

}

public Address(long buildingId) {
    setBuildingId(buildingId);
}
public Address(long buildingId,long floorId) {
    this(buildingId);
    setFloorId(floorId);
}
public Address(long buildingId,long floorId,long longId) {
    this(buildingId,floorId);
    setApartmentId(apartmentId);
}

public Address(Parameters parameters) {
    super(parameters);
    setUserId(parameters.getLong(USER_ID));
    setBuildingId(parameters.getLong(BUILDING_ID));
    setFloorId(parameters.getLong(FLOOR_ID));
    setApartmentId(parameters.getLong(APARTMENT_ID));
    setFloorName(parameters.getString(FLOOR_NAME));
    setApartmentName(parameters.getString(APARTMENT_NAME));
}
@Override
protected void onCopy(Base source) {
    super.onCopy(source);
    if(source instanceof Address){
        Address address = (Address)source;
        setBuildingId(address.getBuildingId());
        setFloorId(address.getFloorId());
        setApartmentId(address.getApartmentId());
        setFloorName(address.getFloorName());
        setApartmentName(address.getApartmentName());
    }
}
public long getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
public long getBuildingId() {
    return buildingId;
}
public void setBuildingId(long buildingId) {
    this.buildingId = buildingId;
}
public long getFloorId() {
    return floorId;
}
public void setFloorId(long floorId) {
    this.floorId = floorId;
}
public long getApartmentId() {
    return apartmentId;
}
public void setApartmentId(long apartmentId) {
    this.apartmentId = apartmentId;
}
public String getFloorName() {
    return floorName;
}
public void setFloorName(String floorName) {
    this.floorName = floorName;
}
public String getApartmentName() {
    return apartmentName;
}
public void setApartmentName(String apartmentName) {
    this.apartmentName = apartmentName;
}
public boolean isFullAddress() {
    return buildingId != NO_ID && floorId != NO_ID && apartmentId != NO_ID;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(obj instanceof Address){
        Address address = (Address)obj;
        if(getUserId() == address.getUserId()){
            return getBuildingId() == address.getBuildingId() && 
                    getFloorId() == address.getFloorId() &&
                    getApartmentId() == address.getApartmentId();
        }
    }
    return super.equals(obj);
}
public static final String BUILDING_ID = "buildingId";
public static final String USER_ID = "userId";
public static final String FLOOR_ID = "floorId";
public static final String APARTMENT_ID = "apartmentId";
public static final String FLOOR_NAME = "floorName";
public static final String APARTMENT_NAME = "apartmentName";
```

}

example of how I insert entity

```
public Base insert(Base base){
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        base.setLastUpdated(getCoreServer().getTimeManager().getCurrentTime().getTime());
        em.persist(base);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return base;
    }
    finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

example of how I select entity

```
public Object select(DarimpoQuery selectQuery){
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    try{
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = 
        em.createQuery(selectQuery.createSelectQuery()); 
        addParametersQuery(selectQuery, query);
    }
        Object result = query.getResultList();
        if(selectQuery.isSingleResult() && result instanceof List){
            List<Object> results = (List)result;
            return results.isEmpty() ? null : results.get(0);
        }
        return result;
    }finally{
        em.close();
    }
}
```

After selecting an entity from dataBase I get the String as "????"

you can see how entity saved in dataBase on this link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5FQ_6n1BT1EUnVFVFJsRFlyVTg
again thank you

Comment: can you please provide your code

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: thanks. how do you create your entity? do you have a web frontend or something like a mobile client?

Comment: Yes I send params form web app (gwt) to server and create the entity in server you can see the constractor with Paramters "public Address(Parameters parameters)" and than call to the method insert. thank you

Comment: did you check in your constructor if every is already encoded with UTF 8?

Comment: in the constructor the text is ok i see the text in hebrew. how can I check if the text is UTF-8? thank you

Comment: please have a look at the accepted answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88838/how-to-convert-strings-to-and-from-utf8-byte-arrays-in-java